# Regarding elastic collision of a projectile in an inclined plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

> A perfectly elastic ball is thrown from the foot of a plane whose inclination to horizontal in $\beta$. If after striking the plane at a distance $R$ from the point of projection it rebounds and retraces it's former path, find the velocity of projection.

> Ans: $u = \sqrt{\frac{gR(1+3 \sin ^2 \beta) }{2 \sin \beta}}$

I have a doubt whether a solution is actually possible or not for this question. I am sharing my analysis below:

[image: Projectile]
In X'Y' Coordinate System, we have $$\vec{u} = u \cos \theta \hat{i} + u \sin \theta \hat{j}$$ $$\vec{a} = g \sin  \beta (-\hat{i}) + g \cos \beta (-\hat{j})$$ So $$\vec{v}(t) = (u \cos \theta - gt \sin \beta ) \hat{i} + (u \sin \theta - gt \cos \beta ) \hat{j} $$ At the moment it hits the inclined plane, $s_{y'} = 0 \implies T = \frac{2u \sin \theta}{g \cos \beta}$. After collision with the plane, $(\vec{v}(T)_{x'}, \vec{v}(T)_{y'} ) \mapsto (\vec{v}(T)_{x'}, \color{red}{-}\vec{v}(T)_{y'})$, I. E., the component of $\vec{v}(T)$ along $x'$ axis remains unchanged. So for it to rebound and retrace its former path, $\vec{v}(T)_{x'} < 0 \implies \cos \theta - 2 \sin \theta \tan \beta < 0 \implies 2 \tan \theta \tan \beta > 1$ Also for it to retrace its path, the equation of path obtained in both scenarios ( or its corresponding radius of curvature) must be similar.

This is becoming too much calculative and is also tedious. I don't know whether I will arrive at a solution through this approach or it. Is there any elegant approach?

Comment: $\vec{v}_{x'}$ can never be negative I guess.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/195139) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/195139).